# How to subtract variable number of days from variable dates using timedelta python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataset that has the original dates in this format:

```
End_date=['Fri, 19 Aug 2011 19:28:17 -0000', 'Sun, 08 Apr 2012 02:14:00 -0000', 
'Wed, 22 Jun 2011 13:33:00 -0000', 'Fri, 30 Dec 2011 04:36:53 -0000'....]

Duration_in_days=[30, 20, 10, 15,....]
```

How do i use loop, datetime and timedelta to subtract the duration from the End_date to derive the start date?

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: I expect the results to show the same format as in End_date. Say the first variable minus 30 days would be 'Thurs, 20 Jul 2011 19:28:17 -0000'.

Comment: It looks like you already got it all: for loop, datetime, and timedelta. If you're confused, look up the documentations. Specifically `strptime` and `strftime` will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

End_date=['Fri, 19 Aug 2011 19:28:17 -0000', 'Sun, 08 Apr 2012 02:14:00 -0000', 
'Wed, 22 Jun 2011 13:33:00 -0000', 'Fri, 30 Dec 2011 04:36:53 -0000']

Duration_in_days=[30, 20, 10, 15]


startDates = []
for date, days in zip(End_date, Duration_in_days):
    x = datetime.strptime(date, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S -0000") - timedelta(days=days)
    startDates.append(x)
```

will set `startDates` to a list of the start dates as datetime objects

EDIT: Or use a list comprehension as suggested in the comments:

```py
startDates = [
    datetime.strptime(date, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S -0000") - timedelta(days=days)
    for date, days in zip(End_date, Duration_in_days)
    ]
```

Comment: why don't you use a list comprehension?

Comment: idk, just the way i wrote it. a list comprehension might be better

Answer (score 0):

The following program shows how to do this, subtracrting the days and ending up with a string-based collection as per the original:

```
# Need pprint for pretty printing of lists.

import time, datetime, pprint

# Set up test data.

End_date=[
    'Fri, 19 Aug 2011 19:28:17 -0000',
    'Sun, 08 Apr 2012 02:14:00 -0000',
    'Wed, 22 Jun 2011 13:33:00 -0000',
    'Fri, 30 Dec 2011 04:36:53 -0000',
]
Duration_in_days=[30, 20, 10, 15]
fmt = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"

# Add each (adjusted) item to a new list.

Start_date = []
for i in range(len(End_date)):
    # Parse end date, subtract and create string from it.

    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(End_date[i], fmt)
    dt -= datetime.timedelta(days=Duration_in_days[i])
    Start_date.append(datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, fmt))

pprint.pprint(End_date)
pprint.pprint(Start_date)
```

And, despite your comment to the contrary, July 20 2011 was a Wednesday :-)

The output shows the original and adjusted times:

```
['Fri, 19 Aug 2011 19:28:17 -0000',
 'Sun, 08 Apr 2012 02:14:00 -0000',
 'Wed, 22 Jun 2011 13:33:00 -0000',
 'Fri, 30 Dec 2011 04:36:53 -0000']
['Wed, 20 Jul 2011 19:28:17 +0000',
 'Mon, 19 Mar 2012 02:14:00 +0000',
 'Sun, 12 Jun 2011 13:33:00 +0000',
 'Thu, 15 Dec 2011 04:36:53 +0000']
```

---

If you're after a more Pythonic way :-), you can replace the loop with:

```
Start_date = [datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, fmt) - datetime.timedelta(days=delta), fmt) for dt, delta in zip(End_date, Duration_in_days)]
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! I tried these on the dataset and it seems that it worked. However, I got the datetime prefix in every element in the output. Any advice on how to fix? [datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 20, 19, 28, 17),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 20, 21, 54, 48),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 25, 13, 33),
 datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 27, 23, 20, 5)]

Comment: @Greenday007: if you're seeing that, it's because you're not using `strftime` to turn the datetime back into a string (the `datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, fmt)` bit). The format you show is the output of an actual `datetime` object, `strftime()` will make that into a string of the desired format (same as when parsed).